# Compiling fmt with Intel C on Windows 32

Tags: fmt

We are compiling [fmt](https://fmt.dev) with the Intel C compiler on Windows 32bit and 64 bit. On 32 bit we get a strange error. Maybe we are doing something wrong but the issue is what? Here is the error message:

```
../master/extern/fmt/8.0.1/include/fmt/format-inl.h(1126): error: expression must have a constant value
      static constexpr const uint128_wrapper pow10_significands[] = {
                                                                    ^
```

Any suggestions for a fix? We could potentially build with MSVC.

Update: format-inl.h (=inline format) is only supposed to be used in a header only mode as far I understand and that is not what I want and has not turned on. So I have to figure why this happens.

PS: fmt is great.

Comment: Add a full minimal example that fails to compile.

Comment: It is necessary that you show the part of the code affected by the error, the error message alone is useless if you do not know the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The expression in question is constant so this looks like a bug in the compiler or possibly incomplete implementation of `constexpr`. The error message is misleading but you might be able to workaround the issue by removing `constexpr` or some other way.

Comment: Agreed it looks like a compiler bug. Thanks

Comment: Intel C classic has the problems. The latest Intel Clang based compiler has no problems. So I conclude the compiler is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building with a C++17 compiler? `constexpr` isn’t a C keyword afaik.